# Not sure how to get vacant units between time period

Tags: postgresql

Not sure how to set up the conditional (or if it requires operations; fresh to SQL) to find vacant unit.

Units are accompanied by start and end date of lease.

```
INSERT INTO lease (unit, s_date, e_date) VALUES (1, '20200101','20200530');
INSERT INTO lease (unit, s_date, e_date) VALUES (2, '20200701','20201231');
INSERT INTO lease (unit, s_date, e_date) VALUES (3, '20200201','20210501');
INSERT INTO lease (unit, s_date, e_date) VALUES (4, '20200615','20201225');
```

i.e.
between 2020/06/01-30, unit # 1 & 2 are vacant and *should* show.

However,

```
SELECT * FROM lease WHERE (s_date NOT BETWEEN '20200601' AND '20200630') AND (e_date NOT BETWEEN  '20200601' AND '20200630');
```

results in showing unit 3 as well

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table definition is bad:

- Never use a data type other than `date` for dates. Neither strings nor numbers are appropriate.
- Use `daterange` to store date intervals.

So this should be:

```
CREATE TABLE lease (
   unit bigint NOT NULL,
   leased daterange NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO lease VALUES (1, '[2020-01-01,2020-05-30]');
...
```

Then your query would be:

```
SELECT unit
FROM lease
GROUP BY unit
HAVING NOT range_agg(leased) && '[2020-06-01,2020-06-30]';
```

This requires the multirange support from PostgreSQL v14. `&&` is the “overlaps” operator.

With PostgreSQL v13 and below, you can use:

```
   SELECT unit
   FROM lease
EXCEPT
   SELECT unit
   FROM lease
   WHERE leased && '[2020-06-01,2020-06-30]';
```

Note that you can use this solution even if you don't use `daterange` in your table, since you can use the `daterange` function in your query:

```
SELECT daterange('2020-01-01', '2020-05-30', '[]');

        daterange        
═════════════════════════
 [2020-01-01,2020-05-31)
(1 row)
```

Comment: Apologies for not showing `s_date` & `e_date` having `DATE` type; I also inserted the dates using single quotes but without the dashes between YYYY-MM-DD

And woah, didn't even know DATERANGE existed (thanks for that)

I'm currently working with v13 but will checkout v14 to use &&

Comment: You can also use that table with v13, as shown in my extended answer.

Comment: That worked with `daterange` - thanks!

Comment: Any chance I could get help with using `date` and setting up filtering for this

Comment: I have added a hint how to do this.